# When viewing youtube.com, can I control the videos from Chrome Dev Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

I want to be able to pause and play the videos from inside the JavaScript console in Chrome DevTools. Is that possible?

Comment: I just created an extension which helps you do from any tab: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playback-control/okbcoijdeebocmahlanbfemnckjonfnh

Answer (score 11):

If you are using HTML5-based player, you can interact with [the `<video>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) directly using [its DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement), as you've been told in Toni's answer.

If you are using Flash-based player, you can interact with it using [YouTube JavaScript Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference). The player element seems to have id `movie_player`, and I don't have any problems using API methods right on YouTube.com:

```
$('#movie_player').playVideo();
$('#movie_player').seekTo(60);
$('#movie_player').pauseVideo();
```

Also, don't get confused by `$`, there's no jQuery.

Comment: $ is googles alias for `document.querySelector` usable in the chrome console API, just clarifying. Good idea to use it since the question was specifically about chrome dev tools. Nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

If viewing using the HTML5-based player, then

```
$('.video-stream').play()
$('.video-stream').pause()
```

OR

```
$('video').play()
$('video').pause()
```

Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods).

If viewing using the Flash-based player, then

```
player.playVideo()
player.pauseVideo()
```

Refer [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls).

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on if you are using html5 or the flash player.

I don't think you can talk with the flash player, but html5 is possible.

You can either send a click-event to the html5-client's buttons or use the video-element's play() and pause() methods directly.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

```
$("video").play();
$("video").pause();

//seems like jquery has some support of its own for these basic functions too
```